# Redirecting "command not found" to a file

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, stderr

So I'm writing a code for a project I'm working on. It's about redirecting input output and error using file descriptors. But there is a problem in error redirection. If I were in command line I would generally do it with this command:

```
    lsa >& out
```

This command would in return write an error message to "out" file saying "bash: lsa: command not found"

In my project I'm doing it like this:

```
    ./proj ls GTAMP out
```

The error is redirected to the 'out' file but it will be:
"lsa: No such file or directory"

Following is how I'm doing it

```c
    //Before Child
    int stdin = dup(0);
    int stdout = dup(1);
    int stderr = dup(2);

            printf("GTAMP\n");
            int fderr = open(argv[argc-1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
            dup2(fderr,2);
            dup2(fderr,1);
            close(fderr);
    //In child
    returnVal= fork();  
    if(returnVal==0)
    {
    char *args[] = {argv[2],argv[3],argv[4],NULL};                
                    execvp(argv[2], args);
                    perror(argv[2]);
                    exit(errno);
    }
    //In Parent
        wait(NULL);
        dup2(stdin,0);
        dup2(stdout,1);
        dup2(stderr,2);
        printf("\nCommand(s) execution complete.\n");
        return 0;
```

Comment: Right, "command not found" comes from bash, and you aren't using bash; if you want to write your own error messages (like bash does), you need to write code that does that. What's the problem here?

Comment: So there's no other way to invoke "command not found" error other than hard coding it using printf? Or is there an alternative to pass in perror or some other strategy which could replace "<arg> No such file or directory" with "<arg>: Command not found"?

Comment: Look at bash's source code; you'll see that `msgid "%s: command not found"` is in its translation table, invoked via `internal_error (_("%s: command not found"), pathname);`

Answer (score 1):

"command not found" is not an operating-system-level error -- those are, as you demonstrate in your code, looked up by using `perror()` to find a string associated with the current `errno`.

Instead, shells like bash actually hardcode the string `command not found`. To quote the implementation (`execute_cmd.c`, from the bash-20180420 snapshot):

```c
          hookf = find_function (NOTFOUND_HOOK);
          if (hookf == 0)
            {
              /* Make sure filenames are displayed using printable characters */
              pathname = printable_filename (pathname, 0);
              internal_error (_("%s: command not found"), pathname);
              exit (EX_NOTFOUND);       /* Posix.2 says the exit status is 127 */
            }
```

---

To compare to another shell, `dash` doesn't emit `foo: command not found`, but simply emits `foo: not found`; this is constructed via the `errmsg` function in [`src/error.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/error.c#n217), as called from the `shellexec` function in [`src/exec.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/exec.c#n146):

```c
    exerror(EXEND, "%s: %s", argv[0], errmsg(e, E_EXEC));
```

...invoking...

```c
const char *
errmsg(int e, int action)
{
    if (e != ENOENT && e != ENOTDIR)
        return strerror(e);

    if (action & E_OPEN)
        return "No such file";
    else if (action & E_CREAT)
        return "Directory nonexistent";
    else
        return "not found";
}
```

---

In short: In neither shell does the string "command not found" originate anywhere outside the source code of the shell itself. If you want your own shell to write that error, you should write the code necessary to make it do so.